# GSON Android, ну вообще никак не понимаю

Tags: gson, android, java, json

Здравствуйте. Таких вопросов тут уже 3 000 000 000.
Но я вообще не врубаюсь, как же так взять и научиться сериализации/десериализации Json, с помощью  GSON.

Есть ответ с сервера вида:

```
    `{"p_result":"ok"}`
```

Это объект типа Json, не массив, не что либо другое.

Мне нужно получить этот самый "ok".

Так же у меня есть пример рабочего кода, получения из массива значений:

```
    User.java

public class User {
private String p_id;
private String p_name;
private String p_last_name;

public String getId() {
    return p_id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.p_id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return p_name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.p_name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return p_last_name;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.p_last_name = lastName;
}
}
```

К нему:

```
public class JsonWorker {

public static List<User> jsonToUserList(String json)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json,listType);
}

}
```

И метод:

```
public static List<User> getUserFromServer() throws IOException, JSONException {

    final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", "spr_employee_get"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_guid", user_guid));
    final String resp = execHttpGet(url, nameValuePairList);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
    if (jsonObject.has("p_result")) {
        if (jsonObject.getString("p_result").equalsIgnoreCase("ok"))
            return JsonWorker.jsonToUserList(jsonObject.getJSONArray("p_item").toString());

    }
    return new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

И я даже по аналогии не могу сделать...

Comment: Если это объект, а не массив, то почему в коде вы пытаетесь распарсить список? Или ответ с сервера совсем другой?

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: @a_gura ну это как я понимаю, что объект. 
Ответ с сервера, как раз такой как я и написал...

Comment: [Сюда посмотрите, я описывал сериализацию в объект](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399489/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-json-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-gson/570313#570313)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String json = "{\"p_result\":\"ok\"}";
Result result = new Gson().fromJson(json, Result.class);

public class Result {
    @SerializedName("p_result")
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

P.S. К слову, в [документации](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) всё очень подробно расписано, с кучей наглядных примеров…

Comment: Сделал вот так и не заработало:


        final String resp = execHttpGet(url, nameValuePairList);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
        Result result = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonObject), Result.class);




    }

Comment: не обязательно что это текст, возможно p_result это переменная enum...

Comment: @Garf1eld, `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp); String.valueOf(jsonObject)` — зачем это двустороннее преобразование? Передавайте сразу `String`, как показано в примере выше. И да, выведите в лог `resp` и покажите здесь, возможно, с сервера ответ приходит с другой JSON-структурой.

Comment: @falstaf resp =""
Вот что в логе.
Ответ от сервера я проверяю, вручную, из браузера.
И ответ представленый, вам, верный.

          final String resp = execHttpGet(url, nameValuePairList);
        String json = resp;
        Log.i("!!!!!!!","server_resp: "+resp);
        Result result = new Gson().fromJson(json, Result.class);

Comment: > resp ="" Вот что в логе

Подождите, то есть от сервера приходит пустая строка? Тогда вам прежде следует с этим разобраться.

Comment: @falstaf спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю с точки зрения рациональности, но такой вариант вполне рабочий: 
Надо, к примеру, десериализовать вот такую строку:

```
{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":10,"perpage":100,"total":1000,"photo":[{"id":"31692962564","owner":"38589282@N03","secret":"69a4da0d87","server":"596","farm":1,"title":"Wall","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"url_s":"https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/596\/31692962564_69a4da0d87_m.jpg","height_s":"180","width_s":"240"},{"id":"31692962804","owner":"136025614@N02","secret":"cc66d3581f","server":"731","farm":1,"title":"Completely Hiding Blogger Widgets from Certain Pages","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"url_s":"https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/731\/31692962804_cc66d3581f_m.jpg","height_s":"167","width_s":"240"}
```

и тд.

и нужно вырвать только поля `id`, `title`, `url_s.`

```
public class GalleryItem {

  @SerializedName("title")
  private String mCaption;

  @SerializedName("id")
  private String mId;

  @SerializedName("url_s")
  private String mUrl;
}

public void deser() {
  List<GalleryItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
  String jsonString = ""{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":10,"perpage" и тд...";
  JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  JSONObject photosJsonObject = jsonBody.getJSONObject("photos");
  JSONArray photoJsonArray = photosJsonObject.getJSONArray("photo");
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<GalleryItem>>(){}.getType();
  items = gson.fromJson(photoJsonArray.toString(), collectionType);
}
```