# Парсинг json с помощью gson

Tags: gson, json, java

Доброго времени суток!

Я пытаюсь парсить json строку с помощью библиотеки gson. У меня есть такой класс:

```
class Foo {
    int Id;
    String Name;
}
```

и, например, такая строка:

```
{response: [123, { id: 1, name: 'qwerty'}, { id: 2, name: 'asdfgh'}, ]}
```

Я пытаюсь десериализовать ее так:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();         
Foo[] res = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Foo[].class);
```

Но при попытке запустить это я получаю ошибку. Проблема тут в том, что строка содержит не массив json объектов, а объект с полем response, который является массивом, а я хотел бы десериализовать только сам массив. Вторая проблема в том, что  в массиве, кроме элементов, которые можно десериализовать как объекты класса Foo, есть еще и простое число 123, которое десериализовать как Foo нельзя.

У меня такой вопрос: можно ли как-то "сказать" десериализатору, что я хочу десериализовывать только  содержимое объекта response и что я хочу пропустить значение 123 в массиве и не десериализовывать его? Или нужно парсить строку и как-то выделять в ней нужные данные? Очень не хотелось бы делать это вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так.

В парсере обратите внимание на использование типов при получении json элемента и дальнейшей его десериализации.

Пример json:

```
var myJson = {
    "one": {
        name: 'Peter',
        phone: '+375294356674',
        address: 'Komsomolskaya st.'
    },
    "two": {
        name: 'Luci',
        phone: '+79032227898',
        address: 'Sovetskaya st.'
    },
    "three": {
        name: 'Jonathan',
        phone: '+44227895463',
        address: 'Golubeva st.'
    },
};
```

Сущность:

```
public class TestEntity {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    public TestEntity() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Парсер:

```
public class JsonToEntity {
    public List<TestEntity> getListEntities(String json){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TestEntity entity;
        List<TestEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(json);
        Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            entity = gson.fromJson(((JsonObject) element).get(key), TestEntity.class);
            list.add(entity);
            System.out.println("Information about " + entity.getName()
                    + ":\nPhone: " + entity.getPhone() + "\nAddress: " + entity.getAddress());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.